# Очень медленно file_get_contents и Curl

Tags: curl, php

Помогите понять, почему такое большое время загрузки. 
Какие тот проблемы с DNS?

Пример тут: http://glowar.ru/test.php

Вот код для теста:

```
        <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <?php
        $iTime = time();
         file_get_contents('http://77.88.21.11');
        $iTime2 = time();
        echo 'Time file_get_contents(\'http://77.88.21.11\') = '.($iTime2 - $iTime).' s (yandex.ru)<br /><br />';
    ?>
    <?php
        $iTime = time();
         file_get_contents('http://yandex.ru');
        $iTime2 = time();
        echo 'Time file_get_contents(\'http://yandex.ru\') = '.($iTime2 - $iTime).' s<br /><br />';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На локальной машине данный код срабатывает моментально. Даже не знаю что и сказать тут. Посмотрел свой phpinfo и сравнил с вашим. Что бросилось в глаза:
Ваш php запущен в режиме `'--without-curl'`

Comment: Это флаги компиляции PHP, а не конфигурации - они не указываются в php.ini. Поэтому, если это возможно, попробуйте перекомпилировать PHP без этого флага.

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз изучаю вопрос как пере собрать php на Fedora.

Comment: Тут подумал, что Curl не виноват, при его отключении file_get_contents все равно тормозит. И тормозят они одинаково. :(

Comment: Тогда я сдаюсь) Люди в интернетах советуют ещё вручную указать User-Agent и выставить `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` значение 1

Comment: Тут выяснил что по IP все конектится быстро. Думаю дело в DNS. Но где рыть не знаю.

http://glowar.ru/test.php

Comment: Не сидел под федорой, но гугл указывает на `/etc/resolv.conf`. Надо написать туда строку `nameserver 8.8.8.8`